# Custom contact form not working with magento installation

Tags: magento-1.7, custom, contact-us

I want to implement [this Contact form](http://www.kontaktformular.com/en/demo/style3-security-question/contact.php) from kontaktformular.com inside a separate folder (named "custom-contact-form") on my Magento root directory.

Eg: mywebsite.com/custom-contact-form

Now, kontaktformular.com gives you whole package with html, php and css files to make and run your custom contact form. [Here is the package.](http://www.kontaktformular.com/en/dlcounter-neu/count.php?id=10)

One of the files that they give out is test.php to send a test mail to a given email address to see if everything works all right or not. This file is has a pretty simple php script to send an email to a secific email address. Now, it doesn't work! And I can't figure out why? Is it because of some kind of PHP conflict with magento installation?

Infact, I have tried many other simple contact form scripts and none of them seem to work.
I want to know the reason causing it not to work. Also, is there a way to add a custom contact form in magento WITHOUT creating a new extenshion?

Comment: "it doesn't work" is a kind of a large area. Can you describe what happens? php errors? mail sending errors?

Comment: well the file test.php doesn't send back any errors, look here http://shopprexo.com/write_your_order/test.php

Comment: Is there any reason why you do not want to use the standard contact form in magento?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

or you could use a lightbox jquery popup.  You would just have to include the js links in the head of the CMS page in question.  This is what I use in my magento site.  It allows me to have a quick link on any page that will immediately bring up my contact form.

http://www.thoughttechnology.com/new/index.php/contactus

http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/

Answer (score 1):

one way would be to create a CMS page with an iframe.

Upload the files to a directory (for example `customcontactform`) in the root. Then create a CMS page in the backend with an iFrame in the content that links to `domain.com/customcontactform/test.php`.

Give the CMS page the url `custom-contact-form` and now you should be able to go to the url `domain.com/custom-contact-form` and use the form.

It's not a very clean way but it is a way.